# cannot resolve the name "xs.string" to a(n) type definetion component

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xml-schema-collection

this is an assignment file. schema must be developed.
XYZ school wants to store the details of student and staff in a xml file. The following scenario helps in designing the XML document.
    Persons will the root tag. Persons will have the entry of each person with name, age, gender, address. A person can be either a student or staff. student will have rollno, standard and section. If staff, then staffid and subject. Every student must have an address with the following entry- doorno,street,city and state.

```
`<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="persons">
   <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs.string"/>
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs.integer"/>
            <xs:element name="gender" type="xs.string"/>
              <xs:element name="address">
                <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="doorno" type="xs.integer"/>
                    <xs:element name="street" type="xs.string"/>
                    <xs:element name="city" type="xs.string"/>
                    <xs:element name="state" type="xs.string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="student" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="rollno" type="xs.integer"/>
                    <xs:element name="standard" type="xs.integer"/>
                    <xs:element name="section" type="xs.string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="staff" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="staffid" type="xs.integer"/>
                    <xs:element name="subject" type="xs.string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>`
```

could anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Change `xs.string` to `xs:string`.

Comment: upon doing that it pops up as invalid content was found starting with the element person. no child element is expected at this point.

Comment: Great, so you've now got a valid schema that is doing its job: telling you that your instance document is invalid. If you don't understand why your instance is invalid, raise a new question (and accept this answer) (and in your new question, show both the schema and the instance being validated).